# Flexible string parser generated automatically by examples

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, named-entity-recognition

Let's say we would like to **parse short strings** (log messages).

Creating such parsers by hand as regular expression is hard. Because there are lots of different log messages - lots of work. And what's even worse regular expression are fragile - it's easy to break parser by slight change in log format, it won't handle slight variations of log messages - all this means huge support work, constant updates and fixes will be needed.

I'm thinking - if there's a way to somehow automate that work? **Provide set of examples - set of pairs** `{ "log message": [parsed tokens] }` and run some smart **algorithm to generate all the parsers**?

Examples looks like mapping `input => desired output`:

```
// parser for request duration
"request http://site/url processed in 200ms": { id: 'request duration', url: ..., time: 200 }
"request processed in 2 sec, url http://site/url": { id: 'request duration', url: ..., time: 2000 }
"request processed, duration 2 sec, http://site/url": { id: 'request duration', url: ..., time: 2000 }

// parser for error
"total failure, memory overflow": { id: 'error', type: 'memory' }
"can't handle request http://site/url ": { id: 'error', type: 'unknown' }

// parser for images
"image /data/images/img1 resized, duration 300ms": { id: 'image resize', duration: 300 }

...
```

Ideally the parser should:

- Be flexible, i.e. **handle slight variations and unknown messages**. It should be possible to **tune** it maybe similar to the **tradeoff between bias/variance** in ML regression.
- Parsers should somehow indirectly use examples for other parsers to **learn general knowledge** about sentence structure, grammar etc. Maybe something similar to word2wec etc.

I'm thinking - if there's a **simple way** to do that?

P.S. It looks like a task for Named Entity Recognition, but python spaCy uses different format to define entities, it requires marking each entity in the message. I can't use that format, **only blackbox mapping** (input => output) as in example above.

Comment: This is a research question, not a programming one. Thus it is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Although a very interesting one ;-) What about supervised classification? Possible a good algorithm could give you the classes with probabilities. Then knowing which probability are the most critical a second algorithm could possible check and proof-read (so to speak) the log entry that seems critical... Just doing brain storming here :-)

Comment: I can't answer your question directly. However, there are parsers written in Python that are, for some situations, less brittle that those written in terms of regular expressions. I'm thinking especially of pyparsing.